# \footnotesize in output stream generates unexpected "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: fontsize, external-files

I am writing styled text to an external file (using the `newfile` package). I can successfully style the text with many attributes, e.g., `\large\mdseries\itshape`. But, very puzzling to me, when I style the text with `\footnotesize`, I get an unexpected "Undefined control sequence" error, and I can't tell why it is arising:

```
(/compile/output.nameofstream
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ... {10}{12}\selectfont \abovedisplayskip 10\p
                                                  @ plus2\p@ minus5\p@ \abov...
```

The following MWE compiles fine and generates appropriately styled text both in the external file and in the output. The external file contains:

```
\relax \fontsize {14.4}{18}\selectfont \mdseries \itshape Text to be styled
```

But when I uncomment out `\renewcommand{\styleForText}{\footnotesize}`, I get the above error message and the external file contains:

```
\relax \fontsize {10}{12}\selectfont \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ plus2\p@ minus5\p@ \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus3\p@ \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ plus3\p@ minus3\p@ \def \leftmargin \leftmargini \parsep 5\p@ plus2.5\p@ minus\p@ \topsep 10\p@ plus4\p@ minus6\p@ \itemsep 5\p@ plus2.5\p@ minus\p@ {\leftmargin \leftmargini \topsep 6\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \parsep 3\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ \itemsep \parsep }\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip Text to be styled
```

I never expected that `\footnotesize` would result in such different behavior than `\large`. What's going on?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newfile}
\newcommand{\streamName}{nameofstream}
\newcommand{\sendStyledTextToStream}[1]{%
    \addtostream{\streamName}{\styleForText#1}%
}
\newcommand{\printStream}{%
    \closeoutputstream{\streamName}%
    \input{\jobname.\streamName}%
}
\newcommand{\styleForText}{\large\mdseries\itshape}
%\renewcommand{\styleForText}{\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
\newoutputstream{\streamName}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.\streamName}{\streamName}
\sendStyledTextToStream{Text to be styled}
\printStream
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with `\protect\footnotesize`.

Comment: That does seem to work. Why is that necessary for `\footnotesize` when it's not required here for `\large`?

Comment: It’s best to `\protect` the `\large` declaration too; it doesn’t exhibit the same problem, in this particular situation, just because its expansion doesn’t happen to contain “internal” commands using the `@` character, contrary to `\footnotesize`.  On the other hand, you might have uncovered a bug: several years ago, the commands for changing the font *style* (_e.g._, `\itshape`, `\mdseries`…) were made robust so that they no longer required to be `\protected`; but apparently, they forgot to apply a similar change to the commands that change the font *size*!

Comment: If you turn this into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in order to bring closure. A commenter (@GuM) answered it in a comment, but never converted it into an answer.

His solution: Use `\protect\footnotesize`.

He gave the further explanation:

> It’s best to `\protect` the `\large` declaration too; it doesn’t exhibit
>   the same problem, in this particular situation, just because its
>   expansion doesn’t happen to contain “internal” commands using the `@`
>   character, contrary to `\footnotesize`. On the other hand, you might
>   have uncovered a bug: several years ago, the commands for changing the
>   font style (e.g., `\itshape`, `\mdseries`…) were made robust so that they
>   no longer required to be `\protect`ed; but apparently, they forgot to
>   apply a similar change to the commands that change the font size!